# Android Service stopped when app is in the background

Tags: java, android, memory-management, service

My app starts a service that trackes positions using the GPS.
The tracking is done using a service created by the app, which when tha app closes can continue to run in the background. This works fine until...
The issue is (i think) that when the android device memory load increases , i think the service gets swapped out and crashes.
Is there a way to force the service to remain loaded? - i would assume not , but if there is it would be helpful to know.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `startForeground` method which is a method in `Service` in order to make a priority. So the system will destroy other applications to begin with.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)

Comment: thanks i had read it (but for no reason) disregarded it ! Will try it and advise outcome.

Comment: It did the trick thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Labelling your service as a foreground component will ensure it isn't terminated except in extreme circumstances, but you are compromising Android's ability to manage its resources.

Another option is to override the onStartCommand event handler to execute the code that your service performs. This method is called by startService and also when your service is restarted by the runtime (Android can restart your service automatically when it gets enough resources again). Here, you can also specify the restart behaviour.

```
@Override public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    startBackgroundTask(intent, startId);  //implement this method, doing processing on a new Thread
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

Using START_STICKY means that onStartCommand will be called again when the Service restarts after being terminated. Note that for restarts, the intent parameter will be null. Use START_REDELIVER_INTENT if you need the original intent again.

Comment: I agree with your comment about "compromising Android's ability".